# npm run storybook error: "You must specify a framework in '.storybook/main.js' config"

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm installing Storybook on my React components library.
When I go with `npm run storybook` I receive this error:

```
Error: You must specify a framework in '.storybook/main.js' config.
```

But in main.js the framework is already specified:

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app"
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/react",
  "core": {
    "builder": "@storybook/builder-webpack5",
    "disableTelemetry": "true"
  }
}
```

Node: v16.13.1

Npm: 8.1.2

@storybook/react v6.5.16

Any clue as to what's wrong?

Comment: Seems okay are you sure the `main.js` file is in a folder called `.storybook` and not `storybook`?

Comment: @LarsVonk yes, it's `.storybook`.

Answer (score 15):

I had this same issue. For me, the issue was because I was using the wrong version of `@storybook/builder-webpack5`. I followed the instructions on [Storybook's migration guide](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#cra5-upgrade) to add the two packages:

```
yarn add @storybook/builder-webpack5 @storybook/manager-webpack5 --dev
```

For me, this resulted in the following in my `package.json`:

```
"@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^7.0.2",
"@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
```

I changed `@storybook/builder-webpack5` to `^6.5.16` and re-installed, and Storybook now works correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, my issue was I had a main.js and preview.js file that was being included between switching branches because they were in the git-ignore. I fixed it by deleting these files and rebuilding.